# user placed markers with infowindows in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm working on a school project where I´m using google maps to make a travel planer. the idea is that the user can drop markers on the map and fill them with text. so far I've managed to load google maps and I can drop markers but I can´t get the infowindows to work. When I looked at googles API it said to make a marker, make an infowindow and the use an addlistener to open the infowindow when the marker is clicked, all the different tutorials also say the same thing but I can´t get it to work. so far my code looks like this:

```
function initialize() 
{
  var mapOptions = 
  {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0}
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng, //map Coordinates where user right clicked
            map: map,
            draggable:true, //set marker draggable
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
    });

  //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
        var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
        '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
        '<h1 class="marker-heading">New Marker</h1>'+
        'This is a new marker infoWindow'+
        '</span>'+
        '</div></div>');

        //Create an infoWindow
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        //set the content of infoWindow
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);

        //add click event listener to marker which will open infoWindow          
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker); // click on marker opens info window
        });
}
```

can anyone tell me what i´m doing wrong? the entire code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/R1bg0gi4

Comment: You're creating a marker on rightclick of the map.  However the infowindow you create and set the content to once, just when your initialize function is first called.  You need to move most of that code so it happens at the same time as each marker is created on rightclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. as commented  by duncan, you must move the code that set's the click-listener of  the marker  into the rightclick-handler of the map, after the creation of the marker
2. the content for an Infowindow may be a string or a element-node, you supply none of them(a jQuery-object)

   ```
   function initialize()
   {
     var mapOptions =
    {
       zoom: 2,
       center: {lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0}
     };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
   mapOptions),
      //Create an infoWindow
   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: event.latLng, 
           map: map,
           draggable:true, //set marker draggable
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
       });


     //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
       var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
       '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
       '<h1 class="marker-heading">New Marker</h1>'+
       'This is a new marker infoWindow'+
       '</span>'+
       '</div></div>')[0];



       //set the content of infoWindow
       infowindow.setContent(contentString);

       //add click event listener to marker which will open infoWindow          
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
           infowindow.open(map,marker); 
       });
   });
   }


   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   ```